# MongoDB find in array

Tags: json, search, mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongodb JSON array and I am having issues locating categories, eg.

```
{ name:"hoyts"}
```

I have tried `{categories.name:"hoyts"}` and a few others but nothing seems to work.

This is my JSON:

```
   {
   "_id": ObjectId("4f67da1538fc5d7347000000"),
   "categories": {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "hoyts",
     "product-logo": "http: \/\/www.incard.com.au\/newsite\/template\/images\/movieticket\/4cinemas\/hoytstop.png",
     "products"▼: {
       "0": {
         "barcode": "25001",
         "name": "GoldClass",
         "Price": "12.00",
         "CashBack": "2.00" 
      },
       "1": {
         "barcode": "25002",
         "name": "Weekday",
         "Price": "12.00",
         "CashBack": "2.00" 
      },
       "2": {
         "barcode": "25003",
         "name": "Weekend",
         "Price": "24.00",
         "CashBack": "4.00" 
      } 
    } 
  },
   "store_name": "movies",
   "1": {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "village",
     "logo": "village.png",
     "products": {
       "0": {
         "barcode": "26001",
         "name": "GoldClass",
         "Price": "12.00",
         "CashBack": "2.00" 
      },
       "1": {
         "barcode": "26002",
         "name": "Weekday",
         "Price": "12.00",
         "CashBack": "2.00" 
      },
       "2": {
         "barcode": "26003",
         "name": "Weekend",
         "Price": "24.00",
         "CashBack": "4.00" 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: what is this 'array()' ? can you post real JSON ?

Comment: I need to only return the products for hoyts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the JSON you posted categories is not an array, but object. If we assume that you have categories as array (inside []), you should use `{"categories.name":"hoyts"}` (with quotes for categories.name) for your criteria. The same thing will work if "categories" is not an array, but object (but I think that you wanted to have more categories, since name of the "property" is plural.

Comment: this is the JSON mongo gave me

Comment: Could you help make this true JSON then please. I need it to be search able

Comment: categories should be array: categories: [ <objects>], currently, your categories property is object categories: {}.

Comment: This should be working, see the MongoDb docs: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29

Comment: Sorry very new to mongo and not understanding can you do a quick demo

Comment: @vucetica: it **is** legal JSON.

Comment: It's legal, but a rather questionable schema. People really need to move away from storing arrays as objects with array indices as field names.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev It is legal what is written now, but it was not in the original text of the question. I'm changing my answer now to correspond to the current version of the question :)

Comment: @vucetica: ah, sorry about that :)

Comment: @RemonvanVliet: array indexes as key names - horrible choice, agree :)